# How to test a component using react-redux hooks with Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I have a simple Todo component that utilizes react-redux hooks that I'm testing using enzyme but I'm getting either an error or an empty object with a shallow render as noted below.

What is the correct way to test components using hooks from react-redux?

**Todos.js**

```js
const Todos = () => {
  const { todos } = useSelector(state => state);

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

**Todos.test.js** v1

```js
...

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Todos />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('should render a ul', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Todos />);
  expect(wrapper.find('ul').length).toBe(1);
});
```

v1 Error:

```
...
Invariant Violation: could not find react-redux context value; 
please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
...
```

**Todos.test.js** v2

```js
...
// imported Provider from react-redux 

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Todos />
    </Provider>,
  );
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('should render a ul', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><Todos /></Provider>);
  expect(wrapper.find('ul').length).toBe(1);
});
```

v2 tests also fail since `wrapper` is the `<Provider>` and calling `dive()` on `wrapper` will return the same error as v1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue after migrating to Redux hooks.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with Enzyme specifically, but so far there don't appear to be any adequate workarounds using the shallow renderer. Better hooks support should be in the next Enzyme release: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011

Comment: Use mount instead of shallow, as shallow only renders the root component and places the custom child components as-is

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I could test a component which uses redux hooks using enzyme mount facility and providing a mocked store to the Provider:

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import AppRouter from './Router'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import StartupActions from './Redux/Startup'
import Startup from './Components/Startup'
import './App.css';

// This is the main component, it includes the router which manages
// routing to different views.
// This is also the right place to declare components which should be
// displayed everywhere, i.e. sockets, services,...
function App () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const startupComplete = useSelector(state => state.startup.complete)

  if (!startupComplete) {
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(StartupActions.startup()), 1000)
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {startupComplete ? <AppRouter /> : <Startup />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from '../App';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);

describe('App', () => {
  it('should render a startup component if startup is not complete', () => {
    const store = mockStore({
      startup: { complete: false }
    });
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
    expect(wrapper.find('Startup').length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: It seems like Redux hooks tightly couple Redux to React components. And by wrapping your component in a Provider, wouldn't you always need to dive() through it?

Comment: I am surprised how come this is the accepted answer. This doesn't answer the question at all, using mount is not an alternative to shallow.

Comment: @omeralper Since the question is "How to test a component using react-redux hooks?" I think yes, it answers the question.

Answer (score 78):

To mock useSelector use can do this

```
import * as redux from 'react-redux'

const spy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
spy.mockReturnValue({ username:'test' })
```

Comment: So simple. My mistake was passing the reducers name on `spy.mockReturnValue()`

Comment: The best option IMO, it works without any complex setup and works for every hook

Comment: IMO, the simplest route to the quickest answer. This works well if your using jest.each``

Comment: how it would work if a component has several 'useSelecto'r?

Comment: Can anyone please demonstrate how to deal with multiple useSelectors. I've just started with unit testing react project. Please someone help!

Comment: A workaround to test multiple useSelector is you can create a hook with all the selectors and then test that custom hook. I know it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: any complementary solution for useDispatch?

Comment: @LarsHoldaas for useDispatch you can try something like this but I am not really sure about it.
const spyOnUseDispatch = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch')
expect(spyOnUseDispatch).toHaveBeenCalled()

Comment: This doesn't work with `mount` from Enzyme. Works only for `shallow` rendering

Comment: This is the MVA!

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useSelector` i got right this

Comment: The simpler way to achieve multiple useSelector is just using this:
`spy.mockReturnValueOnce(value1).mockReturnValueOnce(value2).mockReturnValueOnce(value3)...`

Answer (score 26):

There is another way than @abidibo if you use a function selector defined in another file. You can mock `useSelector` and your selector function, and then use `shallow` from enzyme:

**Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import Button from './Button ';
import { getIsSpinnerDisplayed } from './selectors';

const Example = () => {
  const isSpinnerDisplayed = useSelector(getIsSpinnerDisplayed);

  return isSpinnerDisplayed ? <Spinner /> : <Button />;
};

export default Example;
```

**Selectors**

```
export const getIsSpinnerDisplayed = state => state.isSpinnerDisplayed;
```

**Test**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Example from './Example';
import Button from './Button ';
import { getIsSpinnerDisplayed } from './selectors';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
}));
jest.mock('./selectors');

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should render Button if getIsSpinnerDisplayed returns false', () => {
    getIsSpinnerDisplayed.mockReturnValue(false);

    const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);

    expect(wrapper.find(Button).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

It may be a little bit hacky, but it works well for me :)

Answer (score 25):

### Testing React Redux Hooks With Enzyme's Shallow Rendering

After reading through all the responses here and digging through the documentation, I wanted to aggregate the ways to test React components using react-redux hooks with Enzyme and shallow rendering.

These tests rely on mocking the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks. I'll also provide examples in both Jest and Sinon.

**Basic Jest Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

describe('TodoList', () => {
  let spyOnUseSelector;
  let spyOnUseDispatch;
  let mockDispatch;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock useSelector hook
    spyOnUseSelector = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
    spyOnUseSelector.mockReturnValue([{ id: 1, text: 'Old Item' }]);

    // Mock useDispatch hook
    spyOnUseDispatch = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
    // Mock dispatch function returned from useDispatch
    mockDispatch = jest.fn();
    spyOnUseDispatch.mockReturnValue(mockDispatch);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoList />);

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should add a new todo item', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoList />);

    // Logic to dispatch 'todoAdded' action

    expect(mockDispatch.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({
      type: 'todoAdded',
      payload: 'New Item'
    });
  });
});
```

**Basic Sinon Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

describe('TodoList', () => {
  let useSelectorStub;
  let useDispatchStub;
  let dispatchSpy;  

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock useSelector hook
    useSelectorStub = sinon.stub(redux, 'useSelector');
    useSelectorStub.returns([{ id: 1, text: 'Old Item' }]);

    // Mock useDispatch hook
    useDispatchStub = sinon.stub(redux, 'useDispatch');
    // Mock dispatch function returned from useDispatch
    dispatchSpy = sinon.spy();
    useDispatchStub.returns(dispatchSpy);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  
  // More testing logic...
});
```

#### Testing Multiple useSelector Hooks

Testing multiple `useSelectors` requires us to mock the Redux app state.

```
var mockState = {
  todos: [{ id: 1, text: 'Old Item' }]
};
```

Then we can mock our own implementation of `useSelector`.

```
// Jest
const spyOnUseSelector = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector').mockImplementation(cb => cb(mockState));

// Sinon
const useSelectorStub = sinon.stub(redux, 'useSelector').callsFake(cb => cb(mockState));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answers as it covers cleanly how to test effectively the needed hooks.

Comment: was looking for a simpler way to mock multiple useSelectors instead of writing it using `.mockImplementationOnce` n number of times. thankyou @Andrew W

Answer (score 8):

I think this is both the best and the simplest way to mock `useSelector` hook from Redux store in jest:

```js
  import * as redux from 'react-redux'

  const user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'User',
  }

  const state = { user }

  jest
    .spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
    .mockImplementation((callback) => callback(state))
```

With the idea being that you are able to provide the `state` store mock with just a subset of store data.

Answer (score 3):

After searching for help I combined some of the methods I found to mock useSelector.

First create a function that does some bootstrapping before your test.
Setting up the store with some values that you want to overwrite and mock the useSelector function of react-redux.

I think it is really useful for creating multiple testcases where u see how the store state influences the behaviour of your component.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const mockSelectors = (storeValues) => {
  const mockStore = configureMockStore()({
    mobile: {
      isUserConnected: false
      ...storeValues
    },
  });

  jest
    .spyOn(Redux, 'useSelector')
    .mockImplementation(state => state.dependencies[0](mockStore.getState()));
};

describe('isUserConnected: true', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockSelectors({ isUserConnected: true });
      component = shallow(<MyComponent />);

      test('should render a disconnect button', () => {
         expect(component).toBeDefined();
         expect(component.find('button')).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
  });
```

And the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {    
  const isConnected = useSelector(selectIsConnected, shallowEqual);

  return (
    <>
      {
        showDisconnect ? (
          <button type="button" onClick={() => ()}>disconnect</button>
        ) : null
      }
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: is `showDisconnect` mean to be a prop of MyComponent?

Answer (score 2):

Below code works for me.

```
import { configure, shallow} from 'enzyme'; 
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'; 
import ServiceListingScreen  from './ServiceListingScreen'; 
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import serviceReducer from './../store/reducers/services'; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
 
const store = createStore(serviceReducer  ) ; 
configure({adapter: new Adapter()}); 


const ReduxProvider = ({ children, reduxStore }) => (
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>{children}</Provider>
)

describe('Screen/ServiceListingScreen', () => {
  it('renders correctly ', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><ServiceListingScreen  /></Provider>);
    const tree = renderer.create(wrapper).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `redux-saga-test-plan` cool redux assertion and running library and lightweight it doest all your heavy lifting of running saga and assertion automatically

```
const mockState = { rick:"Genius", morty:"dumbAsss"}

expectSaga(yourCoolSaga)
      .provide({
        select({ selector }, next) {
          if (selector) {
            return mockState;
          }
          return next();
        }
      })
    // some assertion here
      .put(actions.updateRickMortyPowers(mockState))
      .silentRun();
```

Answer (score -4):

this is worked for me as well :

```
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
const store = mockStore({
  startup: { complete: false }
});

describe("==== Testing App ======", () => {
  const setUpFn = props => {
    return mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  };

  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = setUpFn();
  });
```

Comment: You posted the same answer as the main one.